Data is ambiguous. Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples
I'm attempting to train a model to predict privacy based on labels in JSON files. However, after training the model, I encountered this error: "ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous. Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples. 'x' sizes: 1988, 'y' sizes: 1992." What could be causing this issue?
import os
import json
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

# Function to process a single JSON file
def process_json(json_file):
    images = []
    labels = []
    with open(json_file, 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    # If data is a dictionary, convert it to a list containing that dictionary
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        data = [data]
    for item in data:
        image_path = item['image_path']
        label = item['labels']
        # Append image path and label to lists
        images.append(image_path)
        labels.append(label)
    return images, labels

# Function to load and preprocess images
# Function to load and preprocess images
from PIL import Image

# Function to load and preprocess images
from PIL import Image

# Function to load and preprocess images
# Function to load and preprocess images
def load_and_preprocess_images(image_paths, target_size=(112, 112)):
    images = []
    for image_path in image_paths:
        # Load image
        image = Image.open(image_path)
        # Resize image to target size
        image = image.resize(target_size)
        # Convert image to numpy array
        image_array = np.array(image)
        # Print the shape of the image array
        print("Image shape:", image_array.shape)
        # Check if image array has the expected shape
        if image_array.shape == (112, 112, 3):
            images.append(image_array)
    return np.array(images)








# Directory containing images
image_dir = '/Users/norah/Desktop/Privacylables_preprossing/images112/train2017'
# Directory containing JSON files
json_dir = '/Users/norah/Desktop/Privacylables_preprossing/annotations/train2017'

# Lists to store image paths and labels
all_image_paths = []
all_labels = []

# Process each image and its corresponding JSON file
for image_file in os.listdir(image_dir):
    if image_file.endswith('.jpg'):
        # Get image path
        image_path = os.path.join(image_dir, image_file)
        # Get corresponding JSON file
        json_file = os.path.join(json_dir, image_file.replace('.jpg', '.json'))
        # Process JSON file
        images, labels = process_json(json_file)
        # Extend lists
        all_image_paths.extend([image_path] * len(images))
        all_labels.extend(labels)
        # Print example data

# Get unique labels
unique_labels = np.unique([label for sublist in all_labels for label in sublist])

# Initialize an empty array to store the encoded labels
all_labels_encoded = np.zeros((len(all_labels), len(unique_labels)), dtype=np.int32)

# Encode labels using one-hot encoding
for i, label_list in enumerate(all_labels):
    for label in label_list:
        label_index = np.where(unique_labels == label)[0][0]
        all_labels_encoded[i, label_index] = 1




# Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train_paths, X_test_paths, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(all_image_paths, all_labels_encoded, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Load and preprocess images for training and testing sets
X_train = load_and_preprocess_images(X_train_paths)
X_test = load_and_preprocess_images(X_test_paths)

# Print shapes of the data
print("Shape of X_train:", X_train.shape)
print("Shape of X_test:", X_test.shape)
print("Shape of y_train:", y_train.shape)
print("Shape of y_test:", y_test.shape)








import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

# Define your CNN model architecture
model = models.Sequential([
    layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(112, 112, 3)),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(68, activation='sigmoid')  # Sigmoid activation for multi-label classification
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model.fit(np.array(data_list), np.array(y), verbose=0, epochs=100)
history = model.fit(np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train), epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)

# Evaluate the model
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(np.array(X_test), np.array(y_test))
print("Test Loss:", loss)
print("Test Accuracy:", accuracy)


I'm attempting to train a model to predict privacy based on labels in JSON files. However, after training the model, I encountered this error: "ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous. Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples. 'x' sizes: 1988, 'y' sizes: 1992." What could be causing this issue?

It's telling you what's causing it. What part of the error message is unclear?

I think of the way that I am deviding the data to traning and testing
Split the data into training and testing sets
X_train_paths, X_test_paths, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(all_image_paths, all_labels_encoded, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
Load and preprocess images for training and testing sets
X_train = load_and_preprocess_images(X_train_paths)
X_test = load_and_preprocess_images(X_test_paths)
